# Laravel JSON response returns protected data

Tags: json, laravel

```
return Response::json(array('status' => 'Group not found'));
```

returns protected data. Here's the JSON:

`{"status":"Group not found"}`

The following code

```
//$jsonData - the data returned above

var_dump($jsonData);
```

returns this:

> object(Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse)#320 (10) {
>   ["jsonOptions":protected]=> int(0) ["data":protected]=> string(28)
>   "{"status":"Group not found"}" ["callback":protected]=> NULL
>   ["encodingOptions":protected]=> int(15) ["headers"]=>
>   object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag)#317 (5) {
>   ["computedCacheControl":protected]=> array(1) { ["no-cache"]=>
>   bool(true) } ["cookies":protected]=> array(0) { }
>   ["headerNames":protected]=> array(3) { ["cache-control"]=> string(13)
>   "Cache-Control" ["content-type"]=> string(12) "Content-Type"
>   ["date"]=> string(4) "Date" } ["headers":protected]=> array(3) {
>   ["cache-control"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "no-cache" }
>   ["content-type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "application/json" }
>   ["date"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "Tue, 17 Jun 2014 19:03:33 GMT"
>   } } ["cacheControl":protected]=> array(0) { } }
>   ["content":protected]=> string(28) "{"status":"Group not found"}"
>   ["version":protected]=> string(3) "1.0" ["statusCode":protected]=>
>   int(200) ["statusText":protected]=> string(2) "OK"
>   ["charset":protected]=> NULL }

Take a look at `["data":protected]=> string(28) "{"status":"Group not found"}"`. The data is protected for some reason and doesn't appear when I decode the JSON. How do I "unprotect" it (make it publicly available)?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with the Laravel application as you are having. Just as a co-worker of mine said, frameworks make the diffuclt things easy and the easy things difficult

Comment: Facing same issue, have you got any solution on this?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is your issue.

If you look at the inheritance tree:

```
\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
    \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
        \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
```

The ancestor Response class has:

```
public function __toString()
{
    ...
    return ... . $this->getContent();
}
```

So we follow:

```
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}
```

It's okay that your data is stored inside member `protected $content` because when the JsonResponse object is cast to a string, PHP uses the return value of the `__toString()` method to be the string representation of that object.

Comment: This still doesn't explain why using `json_encode` instead of `Response::json` works. The latter hides the data under the `protected` attribute and I can't access it later when decoding the JSON string using `json_decode`.

Comment: I still think this is a non-issue.
Why do you need to json_decode on the server after you have passed it to Response::json (which should be the return statement at the end of your router/controller action)?

Comment: json_encode is a function.  it accepts a mixed and it's return value is a string which is the JSON representation of the input.
Response::json returns an object that you are required to return as the return value of your route / action.
The difference between json_encode and Response::json is the difference between implementation details between a function and an OOP object.

Comment: I'm developing an API for mobile devices. The method returns data in JSON form, but sometimes I want to use the same method for the web app, therefore I need to first decode the JSON data.

Comment: Okay, good.
json_encode is for when you want to encode data to JSON.
Response::json(...) is for when you want to send data to the client, set the correct headers, encode data in JSON, then write it to the output buffer.
There is your answer.  Your API should use json_encode unless it is returning JSON to a browser client... in which case it should use Response::json

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I've successfully used `Response::json` throughout my application when returning data as JSON to a mobile device and it worked every time. I just don't understand why it does not work now.

Comment: You have not framed the question with sufficient information to troubleshoot your server-client relationship.
Where are you performing the var_dump? On the "mobile client" you mentioned?
Is the "API" called by the controller (like a library) or is the API a web service (called by making HTTP requests)?